# How to extract data layer info and display this on a site

Tags: google-datalayer

So I have a data layer with some data and I need to display a couple of these variables inside a html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ttConversionOptions = ttConversionOptions || [];
 ttConversionOptions.push({
  type: 'sales',
  campaignID: '25792',
  productID: '37843',
  transactionID: "ORD010320",
  transactionAmount: "458.19",
  quantity: '1',
  email: '',
  descrMerchant: '',
  descrAffiliate: '',
  currency: "EUR",
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: well this is shown when you look it up with the console

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: sorry updated my code